# Openmpi 1.6.3 on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I manually installed the tar.gz of openmpi 1.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.10. But now mpif90.openmpi returns the following:

```
 Cannot open configuration file /usr/local/share/openmpi/
                                mpif90.openmpi-wrapper- data.txt
 Error parsing data file mpif90.openmpi: Not found
```

How can I get mpif90.openmpi get running again? It was running fine if I install openmpi using apt-get install. But that way I will get only version 1.6.1. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for 1.6.3 and 1.6.1 is not sufficient? You could try installing the three `.deb` packages from Raring [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/openmpi1.6-bin) providing 1.6.3. A quick look on the dependencies seems like it will be of no issue installing it in Quantal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Yes, already posted in the comments as a verified solution, but posting as an answer anyway.</sup>

If the version `1.6.1` from the Ubuntu repositories in 12.10 is not sufficient, you could try installing the `1.6.3` version from Raring (unreleased 13.04 development branch) here:

- [`openmpi1.6-bin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/openmpi1.6-bin)
- [`libopenmpi1.6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libopenmpi1.6)
- [`openmpi1.6-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/openmpi1.6-common)

Download the right `.deb`s according to your architechture and install them like

```
sudo dpkg -i openmpi1.6-bin_1.6.3-3_amd64.deb libopenmpi1....
```

A quick look at the dependencies shows this should work in the 12.10 release as well. This is not a general valid solution, as it's quite a hackish way of backporting.